# Angular 6: Not loading environment when running ng test

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm trying to run `ng test` on my angular/6 project but it can never find the correct environment file. It always loads `environment/environment.ts` regardless. I have updated my angular.json to include the following lines inside the configuration section

```
"test": {
    "optimization": true,
    "outputHashing": "all",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "extractCss": true,
    "namedChunks": false,
    "aot": true,
    "extractLicenses": true,
    "vendorChunk": false,
    "buildOptimizer": true,
    "fileReplacements": 
    [
        {
            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
            "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
        }
    ]
},
```

but to no avail. I have tried running with the commands

```
ng test --configuration=test
```

and

```
ng test --environment=test
```

without luck. Can anybody please advise?